# Issues loading data from Deployd using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, xampp, deployd

I'm just starting to learn some programming and I'm reading Pro AngularJS by Adam Freeman.Following one of the examples the authors shows in the book I created my own. I have a Xampp server and the the data is in Deployd. Both servers are in a Virtual XP machine (VMWare). The data  (`http://192.168.1.40:5500/cars`) looks like this:

```
[{
"brand": "Honda",
"color": "Blue",
"price": 20000,
"year": 2010,
"id": "95d78d0090f3ab62"
}, {
"brand": "Kia",
"color": "Green",
"price": 10000,
"year": 2013,
"id": "47e180e828b2297a"
}, {
"brand": "Toyota",
"color": "Black",
"price": 22000,
"year": 2013,
"id": "19ab0a96f80c29ab"
}, {
"brand": "Buick",
"color": "Silver",
"price": 25000,
"year": 2012,
"id": "a9a217f2a7381994"
}, {
"brand": "Ferrari",
"color": "Red",
"price": 250000,
"year": 2014,
"id": "0abb8a0179f95a17"
}, {
"brand": "Porche",
"color": "Blue",
"price": 60000,
"year": 2012,
"id": "f76556eb6aa7981e"
}]
```

I don't have any issues accessing the data entering the URL in the browser.

The relevant HTML looks like this:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy:'brand' ">
            <td>{{item.brand}}</td>
            <td>{{item.color}}</td>
             <td>{{item.year}}</td>
            <td>{{item.price | currency}}</td>

        </tr>
```

And my AngularJS code looks like this:

```
angular.module("demo")

.constant("dataUrl", "http://192.168.1.40:5500/cars")
.controller("demoCtrl", function ($scope, $http, dataUrl) {
//$http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    $scope.data = {};
    $http.get(dataUrl)
        .success(function (data) {

            $scope.data = data;
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.data.error = error;
        });
  });
```

This is the issue I'm having. When I access the page in IE9 it works perfectly. When I use FireFox nothing shows, and no errors or nothing at all. In Chrome the data doesn't load and it gives me this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.40:5500/cars. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.40' is therefore not allowed access.
```

As I mentioned I'm very new on this, and it is very puzzling for me that it works in IE and not in the rest of the browsers. I also tried the same code using a "json" file instead of Deployd data and it works in all the browsers. Any idea what should I do here? Thanks!

Page in IE9
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your version of *deployd* - run npm update from a command prompt in your deployd installation folder - I had to run it using a cmd prompt with administrator privileges.

There are good answers here:

[Deployd - Data retrieved via AngularJS CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23346863/deployd-data-retrieved-via-angularjs-cors)

Comment: Thanks Mark, but I had the latest Deployed installed already. I figured that the issue started when I installed AVG Antivirus in the virtual machine