# Send HTTP Header Requests with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-headers, httprequest, http-get

I am trying to send a HTTP GET request to a remote server and use the response on an HTML page.
Below is the **project/js/script.js** page

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);

    var config = {
        url:"www.myWebsite.com/discover",
        headers:  {
            "X-Object-Header" : "123456789 ",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    };
    app.controller('discoverObjectCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function (scope, http) {
        console.log('Everything Works!');

    http.get("/object", config).success(function (data) {
        scope.object = data;

    });
    console.log(scope.object);
}]);
```

In my response header, this is what I get

> **Remote Address**:127.0.0.1:63342
>
> **Request URL**:localhost:63342/object
>
> **Request Method**:GET
>
> **Status Code**:404 Not Found
>
> ---
>
> **Request Headers**
>
> ---
>
> **Accept**:application/json, text/plain, */*
>
> **Accept-Encoding**: gzip,deflate,sdch
>
> **Accept-Language**:en-US,en;q=0.8
>
> **Cache-Control**:max-age=0
>
> **Connection**:keep-alive
>
> **Host**:localhost:63342
>
> **Referer**: localhost:63342/DemoSP/index.html
>
> **User-Agent**:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
>
> **X-Object-Header**: 123456789

What I would like to do is send the http request with a customized URL.
So for instance I would like my console Header to display

> **Request URL**:www.myWebsite.com/discover/object

And not

> **Request URL**:localhost:63342/project/www.myWebsite.com/discover/object

Please I need Help on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure the `get` like this:

```
$http.get("www.myWebsite.com/discover/object", {
    headers: {
        "X-Object-Header" : "123456789",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}).success(...);
```

But you will run into CORS issues since the requested domain is not the same as the one where the current script is housed. You would either need to enable `www.myWebsite.com` to be queried in your server environment through the [Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) or if you can change the `www.myWebsite.com/discover/object` endpoint then make it a JSONP endpoint which you can query through `$http.jsonp`.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18426571/1816580).

Comment: Thanks Artjom B. for your comment. First of all when I changed the url from `www.myWebsite.com/discover/object` to `https://www.myWebsite.com/discover/object`, it solves some of the problems I mentioned earlier, but `the status code is still 404`. I used your code to try to see if it will work, but it still doesn't. I also want to keep the root url seperated from the path because I plan to have multiple paths in my requests to the server. That is why I didn't want to have the full URL in the url section of the request.

Comment: What does the developer tools console print when you try to do the request? If it displays a sercurity error, then you need to set [Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) in the application server that delivers your angular app. Are you sure that the request goes to the correct *object*?

Comment: Here is what the console displays.  <br/> `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.myWebsite.com/discover/object. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.` So how do I set `Access-Control-Allow-origin headers`

Comment: It's just a header that you can set on the server. If you use PHP you can use [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). If you are using apache then `mod_headers` is probably the way to go. If you cannot change this in the server, you will have to implement a JSONP endpoint in `www.myWebsite.com/discover/object`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are actually doing is cross domain Ajax call.  There are some typical solutions you can choose:

- [JSONP](http://json-p.org/), use $http.jsonp for AngularJs
- Serve side proxy, which avoid to access different domain
- Use 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

  Here are some links which can help you:
- [AngulaJS jsonp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp)
- [Cross Origin $http with Angular JS](http://orcaman.blogspot.co.nz/2013/07/cross-origin-http-with-angular-js.html)

Answer (score 0):

HttpIntercepter can be used for adding common headers as well as common parameters.

Add this in your config :

`$httpProvider.interceptors.push('UtimfHttpIntercepter');`

and create factory with name `UtimfHttpIntercepter`

```
    angular.module('utimf.services', ['ngResource', 'ng.deviceDetector'])
    .factory('UtimfHttpIntercepter', UtimfHttpIntercepter)

    UtimfHttpIntercepter.$inject = ['$q', '$cookieStore', '$location', '$timeout', '$rootScope',  'appConfig', 'Encrypt', 'appText', 'myDevice'];
    function UtimfHttpIntercepter($q, $cookieStore, $location, $timeout, $rootScope, appConfig, Encrypt, appText, myDevice) {
    var authFactory = {};

    var _request = function (config) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {}; // change/add hearders
        config.data = config.data || {}; // change/add post data
        config.params = config.params || {}; //change/add querystring params            

        return config || $q.when(config);
    }

    var _requestError = function (rejection) {
        // handle if there is a request error
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    }

    var _response = function(response){
        // handle your response
        return response || $q.when(response);
    }

    var _responseError = function (rejection) {
        // handle if there is a request error
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    }

    authFactory.request = _request;
    authFactory.requestError = _requestError;
    authFactory.response = _response;
    authFactory.responseError = _responseError;
    return authFactory;
}
```