# Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: angularjs, symfony

I need to fix an error in angularJs when i make a put call request to an api who was written in symfony2.

I am from  http://ex-admin.com in angularjs and the domain where i make the call is not the same, it is  http://ex.com. I also saw the similar answers for this problem,but I don't fix the issue yet.

I think that the problem is from server where I make the call to this api(http:ex.com) in symfony. I also install the nelmio cors, but the issue remains there. 
Also i want to say that the call works only for get and post, but for put or delete it doesn't work.

Do I have to configure also apache in this case? But the problem is how because I don't know... Can everybody helps me?

Thanks a lot, 
Flavius

Comment: this migt help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756550/angularjs-cors-issues

Comment: You must configure nelmio bundle from config.yml to allow PUT and DELETE methods two, see : https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was this:

I had in app.php $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'] to be allow only the post and get request, and I extended the condition to allow the request also for PUT and DELETE. ($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'] to be post, get, put and delete.

Thank you :D

Flavius